# How do I use multiple reactive streams in the same pipeline?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm using `WebFlux` to pull data from two different REST endpoints, and trying to correlate some data from one stream with the other. I have `Flux` instances called `events` and `egvs` and for each event, I want to find the EGV with the nearest timestamp.

```
final Flux<Tuple2<Double,Object>> data = events
        .map(e -> Tuples.of(e.getValue(),
                egvs.map(egv -> Tuples.of(egv.getValue(),
                                Math.abs(Duration.between(e.getDisplayTime(),
                                        egv.getDisplayTime()).toSeconds())))
                        .sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Tuple2::getT2))
                        .take(1)
                        .map(v -> v.getT1())));
```

When I send `data` to my Thymeleaf template, the first element of the tuple renders as a number, as I'd expect, but the second element renders as a `FluxMapFuseable`. It appears that the `egvs.map(...)` portion of the pipeline isn't executing. How do I get that part of the pipeline to execute?

**UPDATE**

Thanks, @Toerktumlare - your answer helped me figure out that my approach was wrong. On each iteration through the map operation, the event needs the context of the *entire* set of EGVs to find the one it matches with. So the working code looks like this:

```
final Flux<Tuple2<Double, Double>> data =
        Flux.zip(events, egvs.collectList().repeat())
                .map(t -> Tuples.of(
                        // Grab the event
                        t.getT1().getValue(),
                        // Find the EGV (from the full set of EGVs) with the closest timestamp
                        t.getT2().stream()
                                .map(egv -> Tuples.of(
                                        egv.getValue(),
                                        Math.abs(Duration.between(
                                                        t.getT1().getDisplayTime(),
                                                egv.getDisplayTime()).toSeconds())))
                                // Sort the stream of (value, time difference) tuples and
                                // take the smallest time difference.
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Tuple2::getT2))
                                .map(Tuple2::getT1)
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(0.)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i think you are doing is that you are breaking the reactive chain.

During the `assembly phase` reactor will call each operator backwards until it finds a `producer` that can start producing items and i think you are breaking that chain here:

```
egvs.map(egv -> Tuples.of( ..., ... )
```

you see `egvs` returns something that you need to take care of and chain on to the return of `events.map`

I'll give you an example:

```
// This works because we always return from flatMap
// we keep the chain intact
Mono.just("foobar").flatMap(f -> {
    return Mono.just(f)
}.subscribe(s -> {
    System.out.println(s)
});
```

on the other hand, this behaves differently:

```
Mono.just("foobar").flatMap(f -> {
    Mono.just("foo").doOnSuccess(s -> { System.out.println("this will never print"); });
    return Mono.just(f);
});
```

Because in this example you can see that we ignore to take care of the return from the inner `Mono` thus *breaking the chain*.

You havn't really disclosed what `evg` actually is so i wont be able to give you a full answer but you should most likely do something like this:

```
final Flux<Tuple2<Double,Object>> data = events
            // chain on egv here instead
            // and then return your full tuple object instead
            .map(e -> egvs.map(egv -> Tuples.of(e.getValue(), Tuples.of(egv.getValue(), Math.abs(Duration.between(e.getDisplayTime(), egv.getDisplayTime()).toSeconds())))
            .sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Tuple2::getT2))
            .take(1)
            .map(v -> v.getT1())));
```

I don't have compiler to check against atm. but i believe that is your problem at least. its a bit tricky to read your code.